# How do I see the list of addins and plugins in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I think I have a plugin or addin to studio installed which has killed all versions of studio.

Where can I see the list of plugins and addins that studio is loading?  I believe I have gone through all of the menu to find the list of addins.

Would someone point me in the direction that shows me the list of addins?  I will remove them all one by one until I find the one that is "killing my productivity" for the day.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at your packages installed for Visual Studio. They are registered in the registry under:

```
Visual Studio 2008
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0Exp\Packages 

Visual Studio 2005
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0Exp
```

Packages are the complete installs of all addins, automations, and alike.

If you have a lot, I say kill them all.  And then reinstall your specific addons (such as CodeSmith or VisualSVN).  You may need to clean up the addons that were manually added.  But, I think that once you remove the "Package", it disables those addons and automation tools automatically.

For reference, this is my fresh new install of Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on Windows 7 RTM.  Only 1 plugin, and it's for SQL Server's SSIS:

[registery http://eduncan911.com/blog/thumbnail/billrob-stackoverflow.png](http://eduncan911.com/blog/thumbnail/billrob-stackoverflow.png)

Comment: Where are the packages for Visual Studio 12 ( version 11 ) ?

Answer (score 17):

They appear in three difference places, but any given addin/package doesn't necessarily appear in in all those places:

- The splash screen
- Tools / Add-in manager
- Help / About (in the "Installed products" list)

Comment: I know I have addins and plugins installed that didn't appear in these three locations.

Answer (score 10):

In Visual Studio 2013, go to the "Tools" menu and open "Extensions and Updates".
In "Installed"->"All" section you can see it all.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Tools menu and open Add-in manager. Or you can go to the visual studio folder inside of My Documents and look in the addins folder.

Comment: @Jeremy: Add-ins can live anywhere in the file system, not just in that Addins folder. There's a list of paths in the registry (see Gregoire's answer) that tells VS where to look for addins. There are about five different places in there by default, and addins can add their own locations.